# Ruby Watir if then statement

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, watir

I've looked around the internet but without much success as well as checked through here.

I'm new to ruby watir and mini test but i'm trying to write some automation that checks the value in a select list drop down and if it finds a value it changes it a 2nd value. If it finds the 2nd value the next time it runs i want it to change the first value.

I've created variables of;

```
$Title1 = "Dr"
$Title2 = "Mr"
```

and the code I'm trying to run is attempting to use an if, then, else series of statements;

```
#Title
if $browser.select_list(id: "title") == $Title2 then
   $browser.select_list(:id, "title").select($Title1)
else
if $browser.select_list(id: "title") == $Title1 then
$browser.select_list(:id, "title").select($Title2)
end
```

however, nothing happens and no errors are triggered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Tests should be declarative, without if statements--I recommend not doing this at all.

Comment: given the nature of the tests are to make udpates in order to pass to a 3rd party via logs these tests are required. I've since found that i was missing .value before the ==

but thanks for the info though, all appreciated

Comment: The "tests" make updates? Also something I don't recommend.

Comment: in this case the tests are designed to update details of accounts and pass them through a web portal to another company and are required to ensure data validation between 3rd parties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem is that the `if` statements are comparing apples to oranges (ie two different things). You are comparing a Watir::SelectList, from `$browser.select_list(id: "title")`, with a string, from `$Title2`.

For Watir elements, the `==` is used to check if two elements are the same element on the page. The element will never equal a string.

**Solution**

What you actually want to compare to the `Title2` is the selected options of the select list. Watir select lists have a [`selected?`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#selected?-instance_method) method for checking this.

You could do something like:

```
if $browser.select_list(id: "title").selected?($Title2)
  $browser.select_list(:id, "title").select($Title1)
else
  $browser.select_list(:id, "title").select($Title2)
end
```